# Web app : Best technology to develope an interface for a database?

Tags: javascript, xml, node.js, database, web

I am new to web development;

I am trying to develop some web application to view data and do insert and delete on a little database including two tables.
I use Node.js for my server.

Currently, the data is saved in two XML files. I do my operations(insert,delete,...) by changing the XML at clientside and sending the XML over to server to be saved.

However, I guess this is the hard and native way and there should be some library or some technology to help, because this is such a common scenario. 
I also think that using some database rather than XML may help, though the database management utilities are not much needed really.

Note: I don't browse all the data directly from database. the database includes path of some images which are loaded for the user to be viewed.

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest sqlite as the way to go! U will find an abundance of information on how to use it if U google it.

Have a look at this : https://codeforgeek.com/2014/07/node-sqlite-tutorial/ it may be the answer to the question U are asking :)

Comment: @Golnar, probably not an issue given the environment U are using this in, however as a matter of good habits, U should always use PDO for access where possible if using PHP in the future. Also I hope the answer was of help, if it was can U please accept it - Thanks

Comment: Thank you. yes it was rather usefull.